# set headers specified with Accept-Ch using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, http-headers

Websites sometimes send `Accept-Ch` header as a response for example at login time. One such website is facebook. `Accept-Ch` header gives hints to the client, on what client data it should include in the subsequent requests. Example of response header: `"Accept-Ch:viewport-width,dpr,Sec-CH-Prefers-Color-Scheme,Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List,Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version,Sec-CH-UA-Model"`

How does one override the `viewport-width` or `dpr` send by the browser when a JS request is made to the server, if `Accept-Ch` was previously received?